# How can I change "display: flex" to "display: none" when parsing (scraping) a web-page? | Python (telegram-bot) | Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, web-scraping, telegram-bot

Good afternoon. I'm working on a telegram bot that parses (scrapes) information from public sources. Language: Python

In this particular case you need to make a simple screenshot of the site and send it to the user. Link to the site: https://deepstatemap.live/

Procedurally everything is done, but there is a problem, when visiting the site, a disclaimer appears before the first confirmation, namely:

```html
<div class="disclaimer" style="display: flex;">...</div>
```

Accordingly, a screenshot of the disclaimer appears.

Can you please tell me how I can replace the html layout with:

```html
<div class="disclaimer" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

To get access to the exact material I need.

Code snippet:

```python
import telebot
from telebot import types
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from config import TOKEN, URL6
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
import os

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'MAP':
        url6 = URL6
        photo_path6 = str(message.chat.id) + '.png'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.set_window_size(1140, 1140)
        driver.get(url6)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.save_screenshot(photo_path6)
                
        bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id,
        photo=open(photo_path6, 'rb'),
        reply_markup=markup10, parse_mode='html')
                
        driver.quit()
        os.remove(photo_path6)
```

The web-page fragment that is responsible for the disclaimer:

```html
<div class="disclaimer" style="display: flex;">
<div class="inner">
<div class="inner-text">
<h2>УВАГА!</h2>
<p>
Мапу <strong>небезпечно та заборонено</strong> використовувати для прокладання маршрутів евакуації, вона має неточності та оновлюється з затримкою
</p>
</div>
<div class="inner-buttons">
<button class="disagree">НЕ<br>ПОГОДЖУЮСЬ</button>
<button class="agree">ПОГОДЖУЮСЬ</button>
</div>
<center><img alt="DeepStateMap Logo" src="images/meta_og.jpg"></center>
</div>
</div>
```

Result so far:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgkE3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the div as a WebElement and then pass it to `driver.execute_script()` to set the style attribute to `display: none;`

This code should work for you:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D://chromedriver/100/chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://deepstatemap.live/"

driver.get(url)

# capturing the disclaimer div
disclaimer = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="disclaimer"]')))

# setting the style attribute to display: none;
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: none;')", disclaimer)
```